# Explicacion de CONSTRAINT en SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, transact-sql

Tengo el siguiente código de SQL.

```
ALTER TABLE RH_BT_VACANTES 
ADD DESCRIPCION_CORTA VARCHAR(1000)
ALTER TABLE RH_BT_VACANTES 
ADD CONSTRAINT [DF_RH_BT_VACANTES_DESCRIPCION_CORTA]  
DEFAULT ('') FOR [DESCRIPCION_CORTA]
```

Me gustaria saber cual es la función de las ultimas dos lineas, exactamente la parte del constraint

Comment: La penúltima línea te hace la restriccion de que si ya existe esa misma descripcion para una vacante, esta ultima en ingresar tomara el valor de la ultima linea es decir el default.

Comment: En el caso de que al alterar la tabla este campo sea nulo tambien tomara el valor del default

Comment: ¿Has investigado algo? ¿Qué no entendiste de lo investigado?

Comment: google no ayudo? o no entendiste algo en particular?